# React Native cant log specific part

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Okay i got a kind of special problem just with react native i think

Here is the code

```js
       login(){
    fetch('http://52.28.212.104:8081/milltimeLogin', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization':"basic " + this.state.username + ":" + this.state.passw ,
            },
    }).then(response => response.text())
          .then(text => {
            console.log(text['mta:loginResponse']);

          })
}
```

this exact log works in reactjs but not in react native the reason that i have the ['mta:...'] is that the response has the mta: tags so i have to use [''] but i doesnt seem to work in react native. if i just log text i get the whole response but i need to get specific parts of it. Anyone know how to do this in react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make it work this way, read it as `json` object except of `text`.

```js
login(){
  fetch('http://52.28.212.104:8081/milltimeLogin', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization':"basic " + this.state.username + ":" + this.state.passw ,
    },
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json['mta:loginResponse']);
    })
}
```

Comment: This worked my misstake! missed that i didnt use json. Thanks for the quick response =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple console.log command

Use Reactoron for Logging Data 
Here is the link:
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

Best thing for log